# Drupal 7: How do i display a custom field value in my block

Tags: drupal-7, field

Masters of drupal, i seek your wisdom.

1. I have a twitter block and this is the code for the twitter block with the twitter username which is hardcoded.

   ```
   }).render().setUser('kathylynn').start();
   ```
2. The problem i have is, i would like have to the username pulled from my user profile where the user has already saved their twitter account in a textfield i created under the profile.

I've been searching the net for a few days now and can't seem to find the right code to get it to work as I'd like to replace "kathylynn" with a logged in users saved twitter account from the textfield under the user profile. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Use the views module.

Create a user based view as a block. 
In the view create a contextual filter based on user id. Provide a default argument of the current users login id
Call the user twitter field. 
Rewrite that field into

`}).render().setUser('[field_twittername]').start();`

I did this from memory so if it doesn't work let me know.

Comment: Thanks guys, i tried both of em and they worked for me! Owe you one! Wish i could buy ya'll a cuppa joe!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're adding this code directly to a custom block body, just change the filter to the `PHP code` type and use the following:

```
global $user;

// Get a fully loaded user object
$account = user_load($user->uid);

// Grab the twitter username from the field
$twitter_username = $account->field_name_of_twitter_field[$account->language][0]['value'];

// Print your (presumably javascript) code
print "...}).render().setUser('" . $twitter_username . "').start();";
```

Comment: Thanks guys, i tried both of em and they worked for me! Owe you one! Wish i could buy ya'll a cuppa joe!